# Binding stackpanel isenabled to a property does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, inotifypropertychanged, isenabled

I have a stackpanel in my main window called Panel. The Panel's IsEnabled property is binded to a property IsLoggedIn in the viewModel. The purpose of the entire application is it is a store application. A user should open the application and not be logged in, then they can click a button and enter some login info and then click a FinishLogin button, doing this will set IsLoggedIn to true. When this happens the Panel that originally was set IsEnabled=false should change Panel's IsEnabled=true so the user would be able to interact with the Panel. This does not happen. The user is able to login and when debugging i can see that IsLoggedIn changes to true like it is supposed to. If I set IsEnabled=true explicitly like below in the property then i can also see that IsEnabled becomes true. But when the user clicks the button to login, the panel does not become enabled like it is supposed to. The code for the panel is below:

```
<StackPanel Name="Panel" IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoggedIn}">
```

This is binded to:

```
        public bool IsLoggedIn
    {
        get => this._isLoggedIn;
        set
        {
            if (this._isLoggedIn != value)
            {
                this._isLoggedIn = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsLoggedIn");
            }
        }
    }
```

When IsLoggedIn changes to true I want the panel's IsEnabled element to become true. The INotifyPropertyChanged captures the change, because when I debug it is not null, but when IsLoggedIn becomes true, nothing changes in the UI. I tried this:

```
        public bool IsLoggedIn
    {
        get => this._isLoggedIn;
        set
        {
            if (this._isLoggedIn != value)
            {
                this._isLoggedIn = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsLoggedIn");
                if(this._isLoggedIn == true) 
                  {
                    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
                    mainWindow.Panel.IsEnabled = true;
                    OnPropertyChanged("IsLoggedIn");
                  }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have the datacontext set like this:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

IsLoggedIn is in the MainWindowViewModel class.

The INotifyPropertyChanged method is defined here:

```
 public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

The button command calls this method which should set IsLoggedIn to true. It is below:

```
public void LoginChecks()
    {
        LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage();
        if ((usernameList.Contains(EnteredUsername) &&
           passwordList.Contains(EnteredPassword)) &&
           (usernameList.IndexOf(EnteredUsername) ==
           (passwordList.IndexOf(EnteredPassword))))
        {
            IsLoggedIn = true;
            CloseAction();
        }
    }
```

CloseAction is a regular{get; set;} property that is defined in the viewModel. It does the following in the LoginPage window. It simply closes the LoginWindow. This code is in the LoginPage window code behind because I didn't know how else to close the window:

```
if(viewModel.CloseAction == null)
            viewModel.CloseAction = new Action(this.Close);
```

But this does not work either. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @dymanoid youre right, I put the datacontext in the question. And I see no evidence of data binding errors in the output window.

Comment: What's in the StackPanel and how exactly do you set the IsLoggedIn property?

Comment: It should be working the way you show. We need to see how you implement `OnPropertyChanged()`.

Comment: @HenrikHansen I added the notifypropertychanged method

Comment: @mm8 I edited the question to answer your question

Comment: @A.Gunderman: No, you didn't. It's still unclear and how and where you set the IsLoggedIn property.

Comment: @mm8 now check, the IsLoggedIn property is defined in the viewModel.

Comment: @A.Gunderman: I don't ask where it is defined, I ask how you set it. Where are you setting it to true?

Comment: @mm8 I understand now, that should be it

Comment: @A.Gunderman: What does CloseAction() do? Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking a question.

Comment: @mm8 it closes the loginPage window, I put the code for it in the question

Comment: CloseAction is define in the view model and it has a field called "viewModel"? This makes no sense. You need to provide all details.

Comment: @mm8 here is the GitHub link for the project so you can see the whole thing, it might make it a little easier, it isn't that large. [link]https://github.com/Agunderman10/GunderMarket

Comment: @mm8 the viewModel field is my field used in the creating of the viewModel instance. that snippet is in the loginPage code behind, not in the viewModel

Comment: Might be a stupid question but have you looked at the Visibility flag to see what that is set to?  If the panel is Enabled but Hidden then you need to have a Boolean converter and bind that to the visibility property with IsLoggedIn tied to that field as well.

Comment: My guess is that you have multiple instances of the view model and the one you are updating the IsLoggedIn, is not the same instance as the one that is data bound to the StackPanel.

Comment: @DaveM how would I use the same instance each time I want to use it?

Comment: Don’t “set” the view model the way you have in your example. That xaml you have is equivalent of new-ing up another instance and setting that as the DataContext. You’ll need to create the view model only once and pass that instance around to anywhere its needed (it looks likes you have multiple views using the same vm, btw that’s not ideal). There are numerous ways to accomplish this, it’s the basis of OOP.

Comment: @A.Gunderman: What should I look for? Where are you calling LoginChecks()?

Comment: @mm8 LoginChecks are in the MainWindowViewModel class